# Let $I : = (3,1+\sqrt{5}i)$ and $R : = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]$. Show that $I$ is maximal.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $I : = (3,1+\sqrt{5}i)$ and $R : = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]$. Show that $I$ is  maximal. My goal is to show that $R/I$ is a field. So far I have the following:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]/(3,1+\sqrt{5}i) & \cong (\mathbb{Z}[X]/(x^2+5))/((3,1+X,X^2+5)/(X^2+5))\\
& \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(3,1+X,X^2+5)\\
& \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[X]/(1+X,X^2-1)\\
& = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[X]/(1+X) & \text{(since $X^2-1 \in (1+X)$)}\\
& \cong \mathbb{Z}{3\mathbb{Z}}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]/(3,1+\sqrt{5}i)$ is a field which happens exactly when $(3,1+\sqrt{5}i)$ is maximal.

Comment: If $R/I$ is a field, then $I$ is maximal. So, are you aiming to prove that (i) $I$ is maximal, or (ii) $I$ is not maximal?

Comment: Your polynomials are now over $\mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$, so $X^2 + 2 = X^2 - 1 = (X + 1)(X - 1)$.